# Java: Trouble loading file array of records

Tags: java, string, file, records

keep on getting error java.util.InputMismatchException at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source) at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source) at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source) at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
   File order: string string int int

```
import java.util.Scanner; 
import java.io.*;

class PlayerStats 
{       
    public String name;   
    public String team;   
    public int games_ply; 
    public int goals_mde;
}

public class Program3
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {    

    PlayerStats[] players = new PlayerStats[100];
    int nPlayers;
    int opt;
    Scanner in = new Scanner (System.in
    nPlayers = loadPlayers (players);
    } 

    private static int loadPlayers (PlayerStats[] players)
    {   
        int nPlayers = 0;   
        try
        {   
        File file = new File ("/temp/Program3/Player.txt");
        Scanner inFile = new Scanner (file);
        do
        {
                players[ nPlayers ] = new PlayerStats();
            players[ nPlayers ].name = inFile.next();
            players[ nPlayers ].team = inFile.next();
            players[ nPlayers ].games_ply = inFile.nextInt();
            players[ nPlayers ].goals_mde = inFile.nextInt();
            ++nPlayers;
        } while ( players [nPlayers-1].goals_mde != 0);
    --nPlayers;
       }
       catch (IOException ioe)
       {
           System.out.print("\n\n\t\tFile access error!");
       nPlayers = 0;
       }
       return nPlayers;
    }
}
```

Comment: It looks like one of those `int`s is not really an `int`.

Comment: Can you provide file content?

Comment: file content - string string int int - example: LebronJames MiamiaHeat 88 356

Answer (score 0):

I guess you should use `ObjectOutputStream` to write your `serialized` Players object to the file, and use `ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(new File(players.txt))).readObject` to read the object, and don't forget to cast it to Players

Answer (score 0):

check whether your string have spaces or not, if yes then your code won't work as `.next()` will read till spaces

then try this

```
String line = inFile.nextLine();
String [] tokens = line.split("\s+");
players[ nPlayers ].name = tokens[0];
players[ nPlayers ].team = tokens[1];
players[ nPlayers ].games_ply = Integer.parseInt(tokens[2]);
players[ nPlayers ].goals_mde = Integer.parseInt(tokens[3]);
```